# Simple Python Echo Server - Wrong Argument

Tags: python, networking

```
import select
import socket
import sys

host = ''
port = 50000
backlog = 5
size = 1024
server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.bind((host,port))
server.listen(5)
input = [server,sys.stdin]
running = 1
while running:
    inputready,outputready,exceptready = select.select(input,[],[])

    for s in inputready:

        if s == server:
            # handle the server socket
            client, address = server.accept()
            input.append(client)

        elif s == sys.stdin:
            # handle standard input
            junk = sys.stdin.readline()
            running = 0 

        else:
            # handle all other sockets
            data = s.recv(size)
            if data:
                s.send(data)
            else:
                s.close()
                input.remove(s)
server.close()
```

Whenever I run this code, I get this error message for my argument for the while loop:

```
inputready,outputready,exceptready = select.select(input,[],[])
TypeError: argument must be an int, or have a fileno() method.
```

How can I fix this to make the server run properly? Sorry if this is a bad question, I'm new to python and I can't figure this out. Thanks.

Comment: Please indent the code.

Comment: What is your intend with the line `input = [server,sys.stdin]` ?

Comment: What Operating system are you using ? Are you using the IDLE Python GUI or running it through terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah found the solution to your problem their seem to be `sys.stdin` , the python IDLE GUI for some reason doesn't allow you to use `sys.stdin.fileno()` in your code, while if you run it in the command prompt or the terminal it will work fine on linux. [Link](http://bugs.python.org/issue3003)

An if your using windows, you cant pass the `sys.stdin` as an argument to the select() function, as in windows it accepts only sockets as arguments. As Explained in the documentation [Documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/select.html)

> Note: File objects on Windows are not acceptable, but sockets are. On Windows, the underlying select() function is provided by the WinSock library, and does not handle file descriptors that don’t originate from WinSock.

So to mitigate the problem , such that it works on both windows and linux:

```
import select 
import socket 
import sys 

host = '' 
port = 50000 
backlog = 5 
size = 1024 
server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) 
server.bind((host,port)) 
server.listen(backlog) 
input1 = [server]
running = 1


while running: 
    inputready,outputready,exceptready = select.select(input1,[],[]) 

    for s in inputready: 

        if s == server: 
                # handle the server socket 
                client, address = server.accept()
                input1.append(client) 

        elif s == sys.stdin: 
            # handle standard input 
            junk = sys.stdin.readline() 
            running = 0 

        else: 
            # handle all other sockets 
            data = s.recv(size) 
            if data: 
                s.send(data) 
            else: 
                s.close() 
                input1.remove(s) 
server.close()
```